# Nesting columns in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to ask if would be correct the next code for nesting columns in Boostrap 3. I would like to remove the class .row

I'm trying to put columns into colums without the class .row between. At the moment the result is what I expect, but I don't know if in the future it will be a headache for me.

This is a example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In addition, how can I remove padding of nested column because I need a little breathing room inside their div.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the correct code would be:

```
row
  column
    row
      column
```

As can be seen on the [**bootstrap documentation at "nesting columns"**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).

To add a bit of padding in the columns, add an element inside them that adds a bit of padding

```
row
  column
    row
      column
        div.with-padding
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Another question that should I remove margin of row class or not?

Comment: if you remove the margins (i believe they are negative) the grid will stop working correctly.

Comment: @DoXicK one thing I dont find particularly clear from the documentation is why you would need two col-md-6 divs within the col-md-9. 6 + 6 != 9.

Comment: It's because the grid is based on 12 columns where 1 column = (100/12)%. So 6+6 = 50%+50% = 100% of the available width, wether that is in a 9-col div or a page.